# in blazor wasm how to download a file using the a tag without changing the current url

Tags: blazor, webassembly

I have a template on a page.

I want the users to be able to download it without changing the url of the current page.

My code is really simple

```
<a href="@FileLink()" download>@FileName</a>
```

FileLink() is a function that returns the relative file path and name.

It all works fine except for the fact that the url of the page get changed for what FileLink() returns followed by "?"

Comment: That is not how `<a download>`  behaves. Set up a [mre] or it just didn't happen.

Comment: The same problem happens if I remove the download attribute

<a href="@FileLink()" >@FileName</a>

Comment: The "problem" is no problem at all on my PC. Read about [mre]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally found the solution on the web.

Simple solution :

> "Method 2 - make  tag with download attribute, and ...
> target="_top" attribute! To avoid the interception of URL navigation
> by Blazor, we can use a hack.
>
> The hack is, adding target="_top" attribute to the  tag.    download
>
> Blazor doesn't intercept URL navigation in some cases, and adding
> target="_top" attribute is one of those cases.
>
> This solution is very simple, and works fine as expected, as perfect."

https://dev.to/j_sakamoto/implement-the-download-file-feature-on-a-blazor-webassembly-app-2f8p

So my final tag looks like

```
<a href="@FileLink()" download="@FileName" target="_top">@FileName</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just make a button instead and use javascript to download the file.